# Как написать программу без libc?

Tags: c, ассемблер, arm

Вот хочу написать программу которая просто запустится и завершится без ошибки сегментации.

Если я просто пишу функцию `int _start() { return 0;}` то получаю ошибку сегментации, насколько я понял в гугле то надо правильно завершить программу(пару строчек на ассемблере) но какие должны быть строчки для **arm**(я с **arm** ноутбука)?

Comment: Можете скомпилировать к musl. `apt install musl` на любом дистрибутиве, кроме Termux, и затем `gcc main.c -static`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test.c`:

```
void _start()
{
    asm(
        "mov  r0, #0;"    /* кладем в r0 0 -- код выхода */
        "mov  r7, #1;"    /* кладем в r7 1 -- номер системного вызова exit */
        "swi  0"          /* системный вызов Linux */
    );
}
```

Компиляция и выполнение:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c -o test
$ ./test
```